# user search on facebook connect site

Tags: facebook

Is there any way to implement user search in a facebook connect app that would give same results as that on facebook.com?

Answer (score 0):

searching through fql table [user](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/User_%28FQL%29) will give the same results.

or you need exactly the same with group, pages etc? then you have to search in "group", "page", etc. [here](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FQL_Tables) you can get the complete list of available tables

Comment: I just need users in result. But the resultset must match the search results on facebook.

Comment: Currently I am searching user table. but I am not able to search for say "Anna" if the full name is "Annan".